# Reverse engineering ELF: The e_phentsize field in the ELF header is less than the size of an ELF program header

Tags: ida, android, arm, elf, apk

I have extracted the `.so` binary `libTheArmKing.so` (located in `lib` directory in `apk` file) from [a hack of World War Heroes game](https://platinmods.com/threads/world-war-heroes-ww2-fps-ver-1-33-2-mod-menu-apk-unlimited-ammo-ohk-god-mode-radar-anti-kick-more-15-features.120570/) (an Android game) from Plantimod Forum.

`file` output:

```
libTheArmKing.so: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), corrupted program header size, stripped
```

`readelf` output:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          712948 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           17 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         28
  Section header string table index: 27

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        00000134 000134 000013 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .dynsym           DYNSYM          00000148 000148 006210 10   A  3   1  4
  [ 3] .dynstr           STRTAB          00006358 006358 007038 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 4] .hash             HASH            0000d390 00d390 0028a8 04   A  2   0  4
  [ 5] .rel.dyn          REL             0000fc38 00fc38 000c50 08   A  2   0  4
  [ 6] .rel.plt          REL             00010888 010888 0002a8 08  AI  2   7  4
  [ 7] .plt              PROGBITS        00010b30 010b30 000410 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 8] .text             PROGBITS        00010f40 010f40 048398 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 9] .turn             PROGBITS        000592d8 0592d8 000044 00  AX  0   0  4
  [10] .main             PROGBITS        0005931c 05931c 001ba8 00  AX  0   0  4
  [11] .maria            PROGBITS        0005aec4 05aec4 000010 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .ARM.extab        PROGBITS        0005aed4 05aed4 002808 00   A  0   0  4
  [13] .ARM.exidx        ARM_EXIDX       0005d6dc 05d6dc 000f80 08  AL  8   0  4
  [14] .rodata           PROGBITS        0005e660 05e660 00340c 00   A  0   0 16
  [15] .data.rel.ro[...] PROGBITS        00063688 062688 000048 00  WA  0   0  4
  [16] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      000636d0 0626d0 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [17] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      000636d8 0626d8 000010 00  WA  0   0  4
  [18] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        000636e8 0626e8 00063c 00  WA  0   0  8
  [19] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         00063d24 062d24 000108 08  WA  3   0  4
  [20] .got              PROGBITS        00063e30 062e30 0001d0 00  WA  0   0  4
  [21] .data             PROGBITS        00064000 063000 04af6c 00  WA  0   0  8
  [22] .ced              PROGBITS        000aef6c 0adf6c 000020 00  WA  0   0  4
  [23] .bss              NOBITS          000aef90 0adf8c 06dc04 00  WA  0   0  8
  [24] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 0adf8c 000023 01  MS  0   0  1
  [25] .note.gnu.go[...] NOTE            00000000 0adfb0 00001c 00      0   0  4
  [26] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 0adfcc 00002f 00      0   0  1
  [27] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 0adffb 0000f8 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  y (purecode), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.
readelf: Error: The e_phentsize field in the ELF header is less than the size of an ELF program header
```

When I load this `.so` into IDA, IDA cannot detect it as `ELF`, and only show `Binary File`. Also, it cannot detect the entry point automatically.

I think the mod author made this corruption *on purpose* to make it harder to reverse engineering his mod.

[Here](https://transfer.sh/P1Gxoa/libTheArmKing.so) is the binary.

So my question is: How to fix the header of this `.so` to make it loadable to IDA?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1**: Ghidra is able to load and detect this as ELF, but skipped some sections due to incorrect address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a hex editor and set `e_phentsize` (offset 0x2a) to 0x20 it works fine, I believe 0x20 is standard for 32bit.

```
$ readelf -l libTheArmKing.so 

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x00000034 0x00000034 0x00100 0x00100 R   0x4
  INTERP         0x000134 0x00000134 0x00000134 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /system/bin/linker]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x61a6c 0x61a6c R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x062688 0x00063688 0x00063688 0x4b904 0xb950c RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x062d24 0x00063d24 0x00063d24 0x00108 0x00108 RW  0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0
  EXIDX          0x05d6dc 0x0005d6dc 0x0005d6dc 0x00f80 0x00f80 R   0x4
  GNU_RELRO      0x062688 0x00063688 0x00063688 0x00978 0x00978 RW  0x8

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .dynsym .dynstr .hash .rel.dyn .rel.plt .plt .text .turn .main .maria .ARM.extab .ARM.exidx .rodata 
   03     .data.rel.ro.local .fini_array .init_array .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .data .ced .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     
   06     .ARM.exidx 
   07     .data.rel.ro.local .fini_array .init_array .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got
```

Detailed info:

You can calculate the correct sizes by running `man 5 elf` and looking at the `Elf32_Phdr` or `Elf64_Phdr` structure definitions and adding up their element sizes, giving you 0x20 for `Elf32_Phdr` and 0x38 for `Elf64_Phdr`.

```
   typedef struct {
       uint32_t   p_type;
       Elf32_Off  p_offset;
       Elf32_Addr p_vaddr;
       Elf32_Addr p_paddr;
       uint32_t   p_filesz;
       uint32_t   p_memsz;
       uint32_t   p_flags;
       uint32_t   p_align;
   } Elf32_Phdr;

   typedef struct {
       uint32_t   p_type;
       uint32_t   p_flags;
       Elf64_Off  p_offset;
       Elf64_Addr p_vaddr;
       Elf64_Addr p_paddr;
       uint64_t   p_filesz;
       uint64_t   p_memsz;
       uint64_t   p_align;
   } Elf64_Phdr;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me! But how did you find this?

Comment: Edited the answer to provide more information. Fiddling with header fields is a common trick that's easy to implement, many fields can be zeroed or mangled and the executable or library will still work fine.